# what do I have to change in my pg_hba.conf to get rid of peer authentication error?

Tags: postgresql, raspberry-pi

I have postgres running on a raspberry pi, and I was getting the old

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "george"
```

The user `george` is a user I made that can create and access databases, but can't create users. What do I have to change in my `pg_hba.conf` file so that `george` can connect to a dabatabse using a password. This is what my file looks like:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

This is what my connection line looks like in my python test program:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="homebot", user="george", password="xxxxxx", port=5432)
```

This is what I do on the commandline to get into psql

```
psql george -h 127.0.0.1 -d homebase
```

Which works, so....what do I have to change / do to get that connection line to not throw an error and connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new line to the configuration file setting the authentication method for `george` to `md5`.

```
local   all             george                                md5
```